# How to download multiple files in a single request from Azure Blob Storage using c#?

Tags: c#, azure, api, azure-blob-storage

I need to download 1000 small images from my Azure Blob Storage. I don't want to make a separate request for each file. How to do this in c#?

Right now I am using `Azure.Storage.Blobs` and `Azure.Storage.Blobs.Batch` but neither of them have this API. The latter one has only `DeleteBlobs` call at the moment of posting this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> I need to download 1000 small images from my Azure Blob Storage. I
>   don't want to make a separate request for each file. How to do this in
>   c#?

Unfortunately there's no batch download capability available in Azure Blob Storage. You will need to download each blob individually. What you could do is download blobs in parallel to speed things up.

Answer (score 10):

You could speed up the download by downloading in parallel.

```
var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(100);
List<Task> downloadTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
{
    await semaphore.WaitAsync();
    downloadTasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // here download the file
        semaphore.Release();
    }));
}
await Task.WhenAll(downloadTasks);
```

Comment: Took your advice on this one.  Slam dunk.  Thanks!