# Download multiple files from azure blob container through portal instead of one at a time

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a way to download multiple files from the azure portal blob container ?
Download option goes away when I select multiple files. Of course  we can do one file at a time

[image]

Comment: see: https://gist.github.com/SeanDrum/8e7f7387f0aa5e1a9f9d435ea27b4947

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately, we are currently unable to download multiple blobs from `azure storage` in the `azure portal`.

In fact, not only `azure portal`, but also cannot be downloaded in batches programmatically, you can refer to this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60950916/13832613

**Update:**

You can install [Azure Storage Explore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows) locally and use it to download multiple blobs, I did a test, and it works well:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Saved me a big time.