# Azure Storage : How to upload a .pdf or .docx file using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Recently I have been working on adding documents to Azure storage using blob and file share. But then I realized that in file share using rest API I can upload in two steps

1. Creating a file
2. Adding content

I am able to doing that but my requirement here is to upload the .pdf, .docx document at once
and then there should be a way to download them as well.

Could some one please help.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include any code you have written so far and the issues you are running into. With File Storage, you will have to follow the 2 step process. There's no way around that.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am making use of postman to do this for now. I am able to upload the document. Working on download

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no batch download capability available in Azure Blob Storage. You will need to download each blob individually. What you could do is download blobs in parallel to speed things up.

There is an alternative way you can approach using C# or PowerShell.

Would recommend you to please go through this MS document :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files?tabs=dotnet

And this one also
https://azurelessons.com/upload-and-download-file-in-azure-blob-storage/

Reference: [How to download multiple files in a single request from Azure Blob Storage using c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950802/how-to-download-multiple-files-in-a-single-request-from-azure-blob-storage-using)